# htaccess rewrite for codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite code for codeigniter url rewrite.

I have used following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteRue ^list/shows/cid-([0-9]+).html /list/shows?cid=$1
```

note:"test" is my website dir.

It is working well for index.php removal. But it doesn't work for url rewrite

i want make http://example.com/test/list/shows?cid=1

become

http://example.com/test/list/shows/cid-1.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there typo? `RewriteRule`. tip : add `[L]` on last line instead.

Comment: it's not usefull even i remove the [L]

Comment: Have you considered removing the `?` from the `index.php`-removal rule? I think that there is a conflict in the way it is parsed - i.e. there are two question marks (effectively).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [routing capabilities](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) built in the framework?

You can easily add something like this to `application/config/routes.php`:

```
$route['list/shows/cid-([0-9]+)'] = '/list/shows/$1';
```

(*I left out the `.html` part because that is not taken into account if you set it as a URL suffix*)

**Edit: Updated as per OP's first comment (moved my comment in the answer)**:

Right now, all the requests are captured by this directive:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Try moving you custom rule right after `RewriteEngine On` directive, correct your `RewriteRule` typo and add a `[L]` to your rule, as diEcho suggested.

Comment: in fact,the url will be many params ,for example:http://example.com/test/list/shows?cid=1&aid=2&pid=3 ……，you konw,the ci route doesn't support the query string,so i must reach it through the apache rewrite rule..

Comment: I see... your example was a little bit misleading. Try moving you custom rule right after `RewriteEngine On` directive, correct your `RewriteRule` typo and add a `[L]` to your rule, as diEcho suggested (right now, all the requests are captured by the `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/index.php?/$1 [L]` directive).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /test
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/index.php/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^list/shows/cid-([0-9]+).html /list/shows?cid=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: it still doesn't work,i find a same quetion ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153022/codeigniter-router-to-pass-url-segment-as-get-query,so i modify the last line of rewrite rule:RewriteRule ^/list/shows/cid-([0-9]+).html index.php/list/shows?cid=$1,but it also hint 404 not found.

Comment: try after  removing first `ReWriteRule` line

Comment: Perhaps removing the `[L]` from the first rule?

Comment: @mic i have suggested earlier but user said it doesn't helps.

Comment: to ALL,even i remove RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/index.php/$1 [NC,L],it still doesn't work, Does anybody make it success in CI?